# Ability to delete saved entries from a MUI AutoComplete free solo select box

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the Autocomplete function with free solo entry in a React application for a search history type scenario.
https://v4.mui.com/components/autocomplete/#free-solo

The users' entries are recorded to their browser's local storage. That part is all working fine.

However, they want to keep this list clean - if they make a typo on a part number entry, for instance, they would like to be able to remove it from the saved list.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
  <Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    className={classes.field}
    value={reference}
    onChange={(event, newValue) => {
      setValue(newValue)
      setReference(newValue)
    }}
    onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
      setValue(newInputValue)
    }}
    options={searchHistoryReference} // Array stored in local storage
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        className={classes.field}
        onChange={(e) => setReference(e.target.value)}
        label='Number'
        variant='outlined'
        fullWidth
      />
    )}
  />
```

Essentially, I'm thinking the most intuitive way would be to have an X or delete icon that could be pressed on an entry of the dropdown. Such as this:

[image: dropdown]

Does anyone have any idea on how to manipulate the Autocomplete box to include such? Or even if Delete was pressed on the keyboard while hovering over an item. I just need to be able to pass the selected value to a custom function, and then I can sort out the details to edit the underlying data.

**Here's a live example (without the ability to delete):**
https://6mmv9.csb.app/

**And here's the code sandbox:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-autocomplete-free-solo-6mmv9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can check out my forked version of your sandbox code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/mui-autocomplete-free-solo-forked-x83j2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

In summary, few things I've changed are:

1. I added `renderOption` prop to `AutoComplete` component like this to render delete icons:

```js
renderOption={(props, option, state) => (
  <ListItem {...props}>
    <ListItemText primary={option} />
    <ListItemSecondaryAction>
      <IconButton
        edge="end"
        aria-label="delete"
        onClick={(e) => handleOptionDelete(option)}
      >
        <DeleteIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </ListItemSecondaryAction>
  </ListItem>
)}
```

2. I wrote a function called `handleOptionDelete` that updates the local storage search history.

```js
function App() {
  // ....

  const handleOptionDelete = (option) => {
    setSearchHistoryReference((state) => state.filter((opt) => opt !== option));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form noValidate autoComplete="off" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      // ....
```

3. And ofcourse to add `@material-ui/icons` dependency so that we can use the `DeleteIcon` component.

Comment: Excellent - thanks! I was experimenting with renderOption, but I hadn't got that far yet!